# Как получить отдельные фрагменты data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

```
$.get("ajax.php", {tentrs: 1, tentrs_id: 1}, function (data) {
    alert(data.tentrs);
    alert(data.tentrs_id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get("ajax.php", {tentrs: 1, tentrs_id: 1}, function (data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data.tentrs);
    alert(data.tentrs_id);
});
```

Comment: это если хотите получить доступ к полям из ответа, если правильно Вас понял

Comment: да, к отдельным полям. спасибо

Comment: @shamilshakirov если ответ был полезен можете его пометить как решение

Comment: Не парсит. Может есть другой способ. alert был произвольный

Comment: а что приходит в ответ от сервера? посмотрите через console.log и покажите тут

Comment: В data скобок не хватало и тому подобное. Исправил файп.Теперь понятно...